# check if cookies are enable with css styling

Tags: php, cookies

Hi I want to check if cookies are enable when user visit certain page.  I am found the below script but want to style the alert message and don't need to redirect the user.  How do I do that? Please provide sample. thx.

```
<?php
setcookie('test', 1, time()+3600);
if(!isset($_GET['cookies'])){
header('Location:/contact.php?cookies=true');
}
if(count($_COOKIE) > 0){
} else {
echo "Please enable your cookies to use this website";
}
?>
```

Comment: If you don't want to redirect, just remove `header` line and type your program there. BTW, I'm not sure if you would have access to the cookie `test` in the same script you set it (somebody please verify).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What your script not does: Checking if the client's browser enabled cookies.
What it does: Checking if $_GET-parameter 'cookies' is set, and if not, redirects to the a page where this parameter is set.

Check out this answer on this topic:

[Detect if cookies are enabled in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9448424/detect-if-cookies-are-enabled-in-php)