# How to check in a Zend Framework 1 application, whether cookies are enabled?

Tags: php, zend-framework, cookies, httprequest

In a Zend Framework 1 application I want to display a message like "Please activate cookies in your browser...", if cookies are deactivated.

I thought, [`Zend_Http_Cookie`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.http.cookies.html) should provide this functionality, but haven't found nothing like that there.

How to implement this check in ZF1?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detect if cookies are enabled in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9448424/detect-if-cookies-are-enabled-in-php)

Comment: No, it isn't. This question is about a ZF1 specific solution for the problem.

Comment: It's completely indifferent if you use vanilla PHP or ZF1 framework, the solution there could be applied here (though it won't be a ZF1 custom solution, rather a generic one, I fail to see why this is bad...)