# How to scrape page requiring cookies and javascript in PHP

Tags: php, javascript, cookies, curl, scrape

Is there an easy way to emulate cookies and javascript with a php script scraping a web page requiring it?

The current response shows:

```
<body><noscript>This site requires JavaScript and Cookies to be enabled. Please change your browser settings or upgrade your browser.</noscript></body>
```

I put this in the code and it made no difference:

```
$strCookie = 'PHPSESSID=' . $_COOKIE['PHPSESSID'] . '; path=/';
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, $strCookie );
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you would want to do it at the server end rather than the client end?

Comment: The script is parsing to create an rss feed, to then become a twitter feed and the underlying site is happy with the arrangement too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML inside the `<noscript>  </noscript>` will only get displayed if Javascript is disabled. So this is the test for whether Javascript is enabled.

There is [jQuery-cookie-plugin](http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/Cookie) for reading, writing and deleting cookies. But it will not work if Javascript is disabled.

For checking if cookie is enabled with PHP code, you need to set the cookie and read the cookie with another request. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6663901/778687) have some guides on it.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there an easy way to emulate cookies and javascript with a php script scraping a web page requiring it?

No.