# Session can not carry on other pages on server

Tags: php

i have working on a php project.I am using session variables.

i have made 2 file to test this issue.

In Test1 file i have set value in session.below is the code.

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['test']="demo";
?>
```

In test2 file i have print this session.

```
<?php
session_start();
echo $_SESSION['test'];
?>
```

The session value is display blank in test2 file but it display value in test1 file where session is set.which session value is not  carry on other page.this is working perfect on localhost but not working on server.is there issue on server? i have attached server session detail image.[image]

Comment: Enable error_reporting, what does it say?

Comment: mario error_reporting display no errors or warnings.

Comment: **How** and where did you enable it? Does the session cookie get set? We can't tell. Your browser, basic debugging prerequisite.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to "tell" PHP which session it should track?

For example: if your session id variable is passed in the $_GET['session'];

run the following before executing session_start():

```
session_id($_GET['session']);
```

**EDIT**

try this:

```
<?php
if( $_GET['SID'] != '' ) session_id($_GET['SID']);
session_start();
$sid = session_id();
print '<script>window.location = window.location + "&SID="' . $sid . '</script>';
?>
```

Comment: Leandro Barreto i have print ur code and it displayed the following output. also now the warnings are displayed.  output : ebe3blnb4jta25rq3gd3jm2hf4

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: session in /var/www/vhosts/test.com/httpdocs/test1.php on line 5                                Warning: Unknown: The session id contains illegal characters, valid characters are a-z, A-Z, 0-9 and '-,' in Unknown on line 0
Warning: Unknown: Failed to write session data (files). Please verify that the current setting of session.save_path is correct (/var/lib/php/session) in Unknown on line 0

Comment: PHP is telling you the session id is invalid, are you passing the correct session id or is the variable empty?

Answer (score 1):

Check to see if the session save path is writable by the web server.

Make sure you have cookies turned on.. (I forget when I turn them off to test something)

Use firefox with the firebug extension to see if the cookie is being set and transmitted back.

Comment: @chimpmunk0110 how to check that the cookie is enabled or not?

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6663859/check-if-cookies-are-enabled

Answer (score 0):

This has happened to me in the past. You have to be sure nothing is being outputted to the browser prior to session_start(). This seems obvious, but sometimes you have leading whitespace characters at the beginning of the file (before your opening `<?php` tag). Or another possibility is that you're using a text editor / encoding that is outputting some characters before the `<?php session_start();`

Of course, I'm sure there are other possibilities as well, but this one has happened to me before.