# What are the maximum details we can obtian by of some user by making them click on a link & how to get them?

Tags: networking, logging, ip, remote-debugging

I am working on a project & want to get the details of user simple. I don't want them to enter the details which can be easily obtained, or  with some *tricks & hacks*.
I know some things which can be obtained like **IP, User agent** but what else? Can we get the **mac address** or **system build config** or **Computer Name** or any other things?
Also I don't know how IP & other things programmatically . *Detailed* answers or with *explainable links* are most welcomed :)

Answer (score 0):

The [get_browser](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php) function will give you a lot of information based on the browser's user agent.  There are [various ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6663859/check-if-cookies-are-enabled) to check if cookies are enabled.

Using jQuery:

```
var browserWidth = $(window).width();
var browserHeight = $(window).height();
```

will give you the screen resolution.

And lastly, a whois lookup on the IP address can be performed to see the owner of the address block.