# The duration of the sessions

Tags: php

I am having issues with a website I am making.
I need to do a thing like "Facebook" (manage session in the session page, more sessions at the same time):

1. when the user login, I open a session, I give him a token and I store it in a MySQL database. And so far, everything is ok.
2. If the user login, and set "remember me", I open a session, I give him a token and I store it in a MySQL database. But, how can I set a "remember me"? Because if he close the browser, he lose the session token.

I think I explained myself, please help me. I can't find anything in the web! :(

Comment: Put the token in a cookie.

Comment: Thank you for the good formatting! I am new and now I am learning how this awesome forum works!
Is not the use cookies instead of sessions more unsafe?

Answer (score 0):

Mabey you could use cookies instead of session.
so store the data inside a cookie and call it when needed.

Comment: Is not the use cookies instead of sessions more unsafe?

Comment: In my opinion it is both save if you store a token. don't store a password or some valuable information

Comment: But if the user block the use of cookies?

Comment: Most users won't block them and if they do you can check it and just don't show a "remember me" button. [Here a link on how to check it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6663859/check-if-cookies-are-enabled)

Answer (score 0):

Yry using [session_set_cookie_parameters](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php) and set the cookie life time to whateer you want:

```
<?php
  $lifetime=600; // set in seconds!
  session_set_cookie_params($lifetime);
  session_start();
?>
```