# How to set a cookie & if that cookie already exists or not do something

Tags: php, redirect, cookies

**How to do something like this with cookies?**

**If** a cookie exists, **redirect** user to a last used URL on a site or a homepage.

**If not**, **create** a cookie + **redirect** to specific page with registration form.

Can you check if this `php`-code is doing this as defined above?

```
<?php
if(!isset($_COOKIE['firsttime'])) {
?>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://example.com/">
<?php
} else {
setcookie('firsttime',time() + (86400 * 7));
?>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://example.com/"> // redirecrting to registratio form
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Do a "page refresh" ;)

Comment: Cookies only take effect when a page has been reloaded. Read the manual http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php

Comment: do you have to use php code? it is extremely easy to do with javascript. BTW there is a referer header in the Request which tracks which page the user came from

Comment: hmm, i dont know js.. php to but is better i think.

Comment: See this Q&A on Stack http://stackoverflow.com/q/6663859/

Answer (score 0):

You should consider to use a php request rather than an meta tag because its more seamless for the end use. Check out this Thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/768472/4043299

If you want more then user redircetion e.g. store login of user you should use [PHP Sessions](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp). With PHP Sessions you can safely storage data which is assigned to the users active ssesion.