# Cookie vs user settings. Fight

Tags: php, html, cookies

I recently developed a ecommerce site and after alot of issue I think I might have finally figured it out. (see code and question here: [Cart Cookie Issue. Possible solutions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37708668/cart-cookie-issue-possible-solutions) )

What should happen(and does most of the time)

User checks out and pays for items. They are sent offsite temporarily as I am using the Auth.net DPM method which then sends them to my receipt page via relay response. Once on the receipt page it takes the cart_id (the cookie) and adds in the transaction ID and sets the transaction to complete.

What happens with some people

The sql doesn't run at all (due to its dependence on cookie for cart id) and get error that says cart_id is not set. (but cart works throughout the rest of the website to get to this point)

After some tests I found a user that had issue and successfuly resolved it by turning their FireFox settings for history and cookies from never remember to remember. So now that I know what the issue is (or at least I pray this is it lol) what can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You have possibly 2 options:

1) Check if cookies are enabled and don't allow purchases if they're not enabled.

2) If your payment processor allows, send a unique identifier to the payment processor to pass back on completion, which will let you look up your order locally again.

To check if cookies are enabled [see this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6663859/check-if-cookies-are-enabled)

Comment: 1. I will see how it goes!

2. Unfortunately no (or at least I don't know how)