# How to use script to find out why php cookie is disabled?

Tags: cookies, php

Through [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10381978/7936836),php 5.4 in my centos7 server is `Cookies OFF`.
My `php.ini` as below:

```
[Session]
session.save_handler = files
session.save_path = "/var/lib/php/session"
session.use_cookies = 1
session.use_only_cookies = 1
session.name = PHPSESSID
session.auto_start = 0
session.cookie_lifetime = 0
session.cookie_path = /
session.cookie_domain =
session.cookie_httponly =
session.serialize_handler = php
session.gc_probability = 1
session.gc_divisor = 1000
session.gc_maxlifetime = 1440
session.bug_compat_42 = Off
session.bug_compat_warn = Off
session.referer_check =
session.entropy_length = 0
session.cache_limiter = nocache
session.cache_expire = 180
session.use_trans_sid = 0
session.hash_function = 0
session.hash_bits_per_character = 5
url_rewriter.tags = "a=href,area=href,frame=src,input=src,form=fakeentry"
```

Also, `phpinfo()` gave result as below:
[image: Untitlee4d.png]
I have no idea why cookie is disabled .

How to use script to find out the reason?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure that's the correct php.ini? Try making a change to it and look at `phpinfo()` to verify

Comment: @fyroc,I add `phpinfo` result,thanks for any help!

Comment: check the session file path is writable, probably should not be `/`

Comment: @tim,even I change `session.cookie_path` to `''`,still `Cookies OFF`

Comment: something wrong with apache,I find out reason. This question could be closed.